# Execute multiple <java> tasks in parallel in Ant

Tags: java, ant

I need to execute in parallel an automation suite on three different applications. For that I have created a main class in which I am passing brand value as an arg to execute for each specific brand. Here are the following details:

PROJECT STRUCTURE:

- POM PACKAGE- contains all java files of application pages
- UTILITY PACKAGE - contains the common utility java classes for performing common operations like filling the form
- TESTSUITE PACKAGE - contains test case class and main class.

This is the compile and run part of build file I have created for performing parallel execution:

```
<!-- building  all java file 3 times in different target for separate jars to class binary -->
<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${basedir}/src/" destdir="${basedir}/build" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="true" />
</target>
<target name="compile2" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${basedir}/src/" destdir="${basedir}/buildB" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="true" />
</target>
<target name="compile3" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${basedir}/src/" destdir="${basedir}/buildC"  classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="true"/>
</target>
<target name="jar" depends="compile,compile2,compile3">
    <jar destfile = "${basedir}/ClassFiles/A.jar" basedir = "${basedir}/build/"  />
    <jar destfile = "${basedir}/ClassFiles/B.jar" basedir = "${basedir}/buildB/" />
    <jar destfile = "${basedir}/ClassFiles/C.jar" basedir = "${basedir}/buildC/" /> 
</target>

<!-- execute generated jar -->
<target name="Run" depends="jar" >
    <parallel>
        <java fork="true" classname="com.TestSuitePackage.MainClass">
            <arg value="brand1"/>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path location="${basedir}/ClassFiles/classes.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
        <java fork="true" classname="com.TestSuitePackage.MainClass">
            <arg value="brand2"/>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path location="${basedir}/ClassFiles/B.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
        <java fork="true" classname="com.TestSuitePackage.MainClass">
            <arg value="brand3"/>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path location="${basedir}/ClassFiles/C.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java> 
    </parallel>
</target>
```

In the above build file, I have compiled the same code three times to create diff jars for the same class with diff argument. Running this build, separate jar files get created however independent JVM is not getting invoked.

Please suggest the changes I need to make and inputs on the approach I am using.

Comment: What is the output of `ant -debug Run`?

Comment: It works fine...execution begins..but a single JVM instance gets called only..

Comment: Posting the output of `ant -debug Run` will still be useful to look for any irregularities.

Comment: Is there any way by which we can check how many JVMs get invoked on running the build file having multiple jars in parallel..?